# changing the color of the row when we click on it

Tags: jquery

Hello i need to change the color of the row when i click the particular row.. if i click on another row the color to previous row should vanish..and appear color to that row how to implement.. i have the html code  like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/addtable.js"> </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="dummyContainer1">
  <table id="mytab">
  <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="tname"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>RollNo:</td><td><input type="text" id="trno"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Marks:</td><td><input type="text" id="tmarks"></td></tr>
  </table>
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="addrow" value="AddRow">
   <input type="button"  id="delrow" value="DeleteRow">
 <table id="tab1" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>RollNo</td>
<td>Marks</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Of your 19 other questions, only one in five actually received an acceptable answer? If that's true, you might want to spend longer on your questions, making them more clear, etc. If you received acceptable answers but haven't accepted them, please go back and accept them. (But don't accept answers unless they really do answer the question.)

Comment: ok thank you.. because i am new to this site i dont know about that.. k i wl do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class, like this:

```
.selected td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

Then apply it when clicked using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("#tab1").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ymd65/)...or for jQuery versions 1.3-1.4.2:

```
$("#tab1 tr").live("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ymd65/1/).

Comment: @NIck.. this is not working... when we click on the table row which have the id tab1.. the color is only going to apply for... already existing row.. not to the dynamically added row..

Comment: @Mihir - are you on jQuery 1.4.2+? The `.delegate()` solution above is *perfect* for your scenario if it's an option

Comment: @NIck ya i changed into #tab1.. if i select the 5th row it is selecting upto 5th row..

Comment: @Mihir - can you explain a bit more? or have an example page?

Comment: i think you can use live() also...even delegate is better option for this purpose but you can check it once with live().

Comment: @nick ya sure.. i am again explaining my theme.. i am dynamically adding rows here. if i want to delete any one i have to select right! so for that purpose.. i am highlighting the selected row with color. if i apply what u said(jquery code).. if i have 10 rows if i select the 5th row upto 5rows the color has been changing.. and if i click on another row.. the color for previous is still there.. and same coloring pattern is going.. i think u got it now..

Comment: @Mihir - are the `<tr>` elements not siblings?

Comment: @Nick i already posted the code above sir.. tr elements are siblings.. ok if u do this example whats the solution..

Comment: @Mihir - you posted the HTML above...nothing you posted adds rows to the table, so I have no idea what they look like :)

Comment: ok i am posting my jquery.. but u should format that one because it is not understand here. k

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
 var i=1;
 //var rid=0;
$('#addrow').click(function(){ 
 var k=$('#tname').val();
 var l=$('#trno').val();
 var m=$('#tmarks').val();
 $('#tab1  tr:last ').append('<tr id=tabid'+i+'><td>'+k+'</td><td>'+l+'</td><td>'+m+'</td></tr>');

 $("#tname, #trno ,#tmarks").val($(this).html());
 i++;
});
$("#tab1").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
   $(this).removeClass("selected").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
});

Comment: @Mihir - ah, they're *not* siblings :) `$('#tab1 tr:last ').append(` appends the `<tr>` inside a `<tr>`, what you want is just: `$('#tab1 tbody').append(`, since that's where you want it to end up. You can try it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ymd65/

Comment: @Nick really sorry..! wait i wl try and tell

Comment: @nick great boss.. solved.. and i want to perform delete also.. if u have time try that one.. plz

Comment: @Mihir - simple enough :) it would look like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gjDWB/

Comment: @Mihir - it attaches an event handler to the `<table>` that waits for clicks from the `<tr>` elements to bubble up..so it's less event handlers *and* it works on `<tr>` elements added later :)

Comment: @Nick.. oh nice.. now i want to move the rows which are added.. means drag and drop the positions or drag the the row from its position and add to another position like last position..

Comment: @Mihir - Take a look at jQuery UI sortable:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ I'd ask another question if you have issues there...this one has already wandered off topic a fair bit :)  I'm out for the day - moving, but plenty of other very smart guys and girls here can help.